# Arduino: Want to make something only print once

Tags: arduino

I was writing a script for the ardunio so that it would print how far away something was, and I was trying to make it so that if it was equal to the default length (when the script first started) it would not work, and if the distance between the two numbers is greater than 3 inches to print again.  Not sure why it isn't working.  At first I tried to make it so that it would not print, also, if it was the same as the last printed length, so if anyone could figure that out instead, that would be amazing.  Also, sorry if I sound stressed, I've been working on this probably super-simple script for at least 3 hours now.

```
#include <Ping.h>
Ping ping = Ping(13,0,0);
int defaultlength = 0;
int length = 0;
int afterlength = 0;
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ping.fire();
  defaultlength = ping.inches();
}

void loop(){
  ping.fire();
  length = ping.inches();
  delay(100);
  afterlength = length - defaultlength;
  sqrt(afterlength^2);
  if (afterlength >= 3) {
    Serial.print(afterlength);
    ping.fire();
    Serial.print("Inches: ");
    Serial.print(ping.inches());
    Serial.print(" | Centimeters: ");
    Serial.print(ping.centimeters());
    Serial.print(" | Light: ");
    if (analogRead(A0) >= 1000) {
      Serial.print("ON");
      Serial.println();
    }
    else {
      Serial.print("OFF");
      Serial.println();
    }

  }

  delay(1000);

}
```

Also, It is not printing anything at all ever.  I'm not sure if its not going through the loop or what.

Comment: You say "Not sure why it isn't working." What are you expecting? What is it doing that is different?

Comment: When things like this don't work, you should consider dumping information near statements "where nothing is supposed to happen" - just litter your code with Serial.print() statements, and dump everything that is going on.

Comment: Also - when you are debugging code, take out "everything you can do without". For example, you could take out the lines that poll A0, take out the bits that print the ping in cm, and just print out the value of the ping every time you go through the loop. Usually that clears things up a lot.

Comment: Print something before the if statement... that will tell you if you are even executing the loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line `sqrt(afterlength^2);` doesn't do anything useful. Did you mean to take the absolute value by writing

```
afterlength = sqrt(afterlength*afterlength);
```

The ^ operator is the [bitwise XOR](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/BitwiseAnd) -- not at all what you were trying to do.

Does that make it better?

As for your other question:
"At first I tried to make it so that it would not print, also, if it was the same as the last printed length, so if anyone could figure that out instead, that would be amazing." - here is what you can do:

1) define another variable in the head of the script - call it `lastlength` and initialize it to defaultlength (right after you did your first ping in `setup()`)

2) in the loop, change the if statement to

```
if ((afterlength >= 3) && (abs(length - lastlength) > 0.1)) {
```

3) finally, at the end of your if{} statement, add:

```
lastlength = length;
```

The reason to put that in the `if{}` block is to make sure that you only update it if things have changed sufficiently - otherwise, you keep the same "don't tell me again until it's different than the number you told me before" value. Of course, the `> 0.1` value can be replaced with whatever tolerance you want. Note also use of abs() - a bit more compact than the square root of the square.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant to do.

Comment: Did it help when you fixed that?

Comment: Apprently, however, the square root of -143^2 = 0.

Comment: You should using floating point, not int, as your variable type... and use afterlength * afterlength rather than ^2. ^ is the bitwise XOR operator, which is not what you want!

Comment: Then you can "accept" the answer and go back to your toy. You might even "up vote" it. I'm going to answer the other question you had - not to print if it's "like the last answer". Watch this space... Good luck!

Comment: I get this "sketch_jan26a:19: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token" when I do the last length thing

Comment: It may be there were some parentheses missing - please check the code now, I added some. If it doesn't work, you'll just have to go back to the previous version, which was working. Or start a new question with the current source code.